# Issues after moving function to separate file

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Below is the code of my `initState` and `ListView.builder`. The `refreshShoppingItems` function has been moved to a different file. Now my `ListView.builder` does not show any information from my sqflite database anymore

```
ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: shoppingItems.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GenericTile(
                  gradient: const LinearGradient(colors: [
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 80, 107, 86),
                    Color.fromARGB(255, 16, 187, 121),
                  ]),
                  taskName: shoppingItems[index]['title'],
                  taskCompleted: false,
                  onTapped: () {},
                  showDeleteButton: true,
                  showEditButton: true,
                  onDeletePressed: () => deleteShoppingItem(
                    shoppingItems[index]['id'],
                    context,
                  ),
                  onEditPressed: () => _showItemForm(
                    shoppingItems[index]['id'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),

  @override
void initState() {
_tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
super.initState();
refreshShoppingItems(data, _isLoading, () {
  setState(() {
    shoppingItems = data;
  });
});
print("..number of items ${shoppingItems.length}");
}

void refreshShoppingItems(
List shoppingItems,
bool isLoading,
Function setState,
) async {
final data = await SQLHelper_Shopping.getItems();
setState(() {
shoppingItems.clear();
shoppingItems.addAll(data);
 });
  }
```

Editing a couple of things but im kinda stuck

Comment: why did you decide to move the method? its purpose is changing the ui of stateful widget, it belongs within state class. I am positively sure your problem is caused by incorrect use of setState((){}) that you pass as a parameter function but then treat it like if you were just calling setState((){}) normally from State class. I strongly suggest reconsidering your decision about moving the method.

Comment: I want all my logic (i have moved some other functions too) in a separate file.

Comment: I am sorry, but "I want" is not a valid argument. Calling setState from a different file is not a good practice. However, separating state management from UI level definitely is a good practice. Do you use any state management solution? Like BLoC, Provider, Redux, etc? If you do, it should be the layer between your UI and data providers (like your sqlhelper). If not, consider doing so, or just make sure whatever you are separating in different file doesn't contain setState((){})

Comment: Ok, i do use bloc somewhere in my code (for the login logic). Perhaps i should first reverse the changes i have made to my code. When i start finishing my app i will implement BLOC for this part too.

Comment: I have reverted back to a previous git commit. Thanks for thinking with me Olga.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting back to a previous commit has solved my issues. I will tackle this in a later state when adding proper state management for this part of the app.